# What is the difference between "to look carefully at something" and "to look at something carefully"?

Tags: collocations, adverb-placement

What is the difference (if any) between the following?

> 1. 'to look carefully at something'
> 2. 'to look at something carefully'

I am trying to understand which place the word 'carefully' should be used in. It seems as though you can have it in different positions in a sentence but the meaning  alters. I am not sure I do get the difference.

I have come across the following sentence in one of the tests for level A2 (Focus Level 2 by Pearson):

> 'I was looking carefully at it (=a mobile phone) to see who it belonged to.'

It makes me wonder whether I can move 'carefully' to a different position in the sentence and whether the meaning will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

This is the case of proper adverb placement. Most adverbs can be classified into 10 different types. See the types here in Cambridge: [Types of adverbs and their positions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position). *Different types of adverbs go in different places [there are exceptions though]*.

*"Carefully"* is an adverb of the type *manner* (how something is done). Adverbs of *manner* can be placed in the mid-position or in the end position (depending on the intended effect).

According to Cambridge (from the linked source), adverbs of manner *"usually go in end position."* This is true if you want to focus or emphasize on how something is done or is being done (e.g., slowly, quickly, loudly, gently). *"If the verb has an object, the adverb comes after the object"*.

> She ate **quickly**. He ran to the store **quickly**. He looked at the numbers **carefully**.

*"They sometimes go in mid position if the adverb is not the most important part of the clause or if the object is very long."*

> She quickly ate her dinner and ran out.
>
> He carefully looked at the numbers and found huge discrepancies in the sales records.

---

The Chicago Manual of Style (16th Ed) says *"to avoid miscues, an adverb should generally be placed as near as possible to the word it is intended to modify."* - 5.167: Placement of adverbs

For example, what does *"immediately"* modify in the following sentence—*compete or submitted?*

> *"... the marathoners submitted their applications to compete **immediately**."*

Here, *"immediately"* needs to be placed right before the verb it actually modifies—*submitted*.

If an adverb modifies a verb phrase, it should be placed between the auxiliary verb and the principal verb.

> *"... the administration **has repudiated** this view."*
>
> *"... the administration **has consistently repudiated** this view."*
>
> I **have thoroughly studied** every single chapter for the test.
>
> He **has carefully looked** at the numbers; he is now ready to fire the sales manager for stealing from the company.

Based on this, your example sentence should be

> "I **was carefully looking** <s>carefully</s> at it (=a mobile phone) to see who it belonged to."

---

*"If an adverb qualifies an adjective, an adverb, a preposition, or a conjunction, it should immediately precede the word [that is] qualified"*.

Comment: so you mean to say the example I gave is grammatically wrong?

Comment: @Yukatan I am not sure which one you are referring to. The A2 example isn't *wrong*, it just doesn't conform to the guidelines that I mentioned (Cambridge and Chicago). Someone else may say that is fine as per some other guideline or rule. I don't think changing the adverb position slightly makes the sentence ungrammatical.